# Adding Header to a DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a DataFrame:

```
Index   1   Dr. Santosh Kumar
0      NaN  BHR/ 6681/148/1/134094/2007-08/L
1      NaN  B/301, Laxmi Apartment
2      NaN  New Chitragupta Nagar, Kankerbagh
3      NaN  Patna â€“ 800 020
4      NaN  NaN
5      2    Dr. Deepak Kumar
6      NaN  BHR/ 6682/148/2/134095/2007-08/L
7      NaN  At & P.o-  Bairia
8      NaN  P.s- Gourichak
9      NaN  Patna â€“ 800 007
```

i want to add an header to this dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([df],columns = ["id","information"])
```

but i get this error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (2, 1)
```

so final output should be:

```
Index   id  information
0       1   Dr. Santosh Kumar
1       NaN BHR/ 6681/148/1/134094/2007-08/L
2       NaN B/301, Laxmi Apartment
3       NaN New Chitragupta Nagar, Kankerbagh
4       NaN Patna â€“ 800 020
5       NaN NaN
6       2   Dr. Deepak Kumar
7       NaN BHR/ 6682/148/2/134095/2007-08/L
8       NaN At & P.o-  Bairia
9       NaN P.s- Gourichak
10      NaN Patna â€“ 800 007
```

Comment: How working `df.columns = ["id","information"]` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.row_stack([df.columns, df.values]),
    columns=['id', 'information']
)
```

Comment: This line,adds a header to the existing data frame

Answer (score 9):

You can add columns names by parameter `names` in `read_csv` if no header file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=["id","information"])
```

If want set columns names by list:

```
df.columns = ["id","information"]
```

Comment: but i'm not reading a csv, i'm using tabula to parse a pdf to dataframe, in that way, i will have a dataframe as output with out headers.

Comment: df.columns is not adding a header, it replacing the existing first row.

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar - Yes, it was a bit unclear. But I have one idea - how is created original `df` from pdf ?