# Dataframe header

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
       A    B    C
Date
data data data data
data data data data
```

how can I add header to make it looks like this:

```
       All Data
Type   A    B    C
Date
data data data data
data data data data
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479310/adding-header-to-a-dataframe-pandas

Comment: Did your query solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be using `concat()`:

```
df=pd.concat({'All Data':df},axis=1,names=[None,'Type'])
```

OR

use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['All Data'],df.columns],names=[None,'Type'])
```

OR

use `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays()`

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['All Data']*len(df.columns),df.columns],names=[None,'Type'])
```

output of `df`:

```
        All Data
Type    A       B       C
Date            
data    data    data    data
data    data    data    data
```

**Update:** If you want to show the header in middle then use `style.set_table_styles()`:

```
df=df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])
```

output of `df`:

```
             All Data
Type    A       B       C
Date            
data    data    data    data
data    data    data    data
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! I tried these codes, but the header "All date" always displayed at the right instead of in the center. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Vicki it's display like that in jupyter or spyder but when you save to to excel it will appear in center

Comment: @Vicki see this answer it will solve your problem of displaying header https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360291/14289892.....use `df=df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')])])`.....and updated answer...kindly check **:)**